# How to add remote repository using Sourcetree

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using a Mac and I'm new to Bitbucket and Sourcetree. I want to push my local repository to a remote repository. So in Sourcetree, I pressed "New", "clone from Url" and I pasted the url right from our remote repository. When I press enter, it says the url isn't valid.

I kinda rushed through the installation, so maybe that could be it.

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing the actual URL or where it's hosted. Check that (1) it is _indeed_ a valid git URL (ex. it doesn't have `localhost` instead of a domain name or an IP, it ends with a `.git`, etc.) and (2) your Mac can actually access that URL (ex. try loading it in a browser)

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming your local folder is initialized with `git`.

There are two ways you can achieve this:

**Via Sourcetree app:**

1. In Sourcetree, check the left pane for `Remotes`

[image]

2. Right click on it and select `New Remote`

[image]

3. Insert the link to your repo and click on OK
4. Once that's done, just do a Pull from your branch and commit your changes to the repo

**Via Terminal (the easy way)**

1. `cd /path/to/your/repo`
2. `git remote add origin https://remote_url_of_your_repo`
3. `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 1):

What Sahan said is correct. But what solved my issue was I had to create a folder **first** in the remote repository.