# Link remote repository with already downloaded files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

we work on remote repositories which are quite big.

Normally when I need to checkout the repository I use *sourcetree => clone* and there I provide link to the remote repository.

The problem is my slow internet - checking out a new repository from scratch the usual way takes ages.

However, I managed to get our current develop files. So what I would dream of, would be to tell the Sourcee:

The files are here, do not download anything, just check for any changes (there shouldn't be any) and link this to the remote repository. And then I would like to be able to push/pull to the remote as if it was created the usual way.

I tried to choose the directory with the downloaded files as a destination for clone, but sourcetree requires the location to be empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add remote repository using Sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091933/how-to-add-remote-repository-using-sourcetree)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3311824/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/18999726/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+into+non-empty+directory

Comment: @JimRedmond - I don't think so. It seems to me, the thread is about initializing a new repo with local files. I need something else: Basically a checkout but with pre-downloaded files.